# Can light travel in closed loops indefinitely?

Tags: optics, refraction, variational-principle, dissipation

For simplicity, consider the two dimensional space. My question is that can there be a refractive index $(x, y)\mapsto n(x, y)$ such that the there is at least one closed permissible path (which can be evaluated by Fermat's principle, for instance)?

If so, does this make sense "physically"? Will light just go in indefinitely traversing that loop, as if being trapped in it?

Comment: You could. Each time the light ray interacts with a different point in the medium, some of its energy is absorbed. So it can’t happen indefinitely.

Comment: Why was this closed?  The question seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @garyp Exactly! Sometimes SE just makes no sense.

Comment: I think adding a diagram would help. In any case, take an optical fibre and splice it to make a closed loop - and here is your closed optical path. Assuming loss-less dielectrics and making your cladding thicker and bend radius larger you can push losses as far down as you want. More generally, [transformation optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_optics) gives tools to deal with such questions. For this case you want a transform that maps x-axis to angle and y-axis to radius in cylindrical coordinates (maps upper XY-half-space into 2d cylindrical coords space)